# When is using multiple tables the right solution to reducing table size?

Tags: mysql, sql

After reading about foreign keys and references on MySQL, I got this question in my mind.

If you run an email marketing service, and let your users create contact lists, that will hold tons of records, thousands probably a million or two, would it be better idea to have one table for each user's contact list? Or one big table that has all the contacts ever added to the website, and reference them to the list the belong?

If you have 50,000 users, and each of them has 2 contact lists each of 10,000 emails, you have 1 million emails logged into 1 single table. Wouldn't it be too intensive to run a select query on that table like...

```
SELECT * FROM name_of_the_big_table
    WHERE belonging_contact_list = id_of_the_contact_list
```

Comment: Can a user share their contact list (or a subset thereof) with another user?

Comment: 1 million records is nothing for MySQL if you set your table up right, especially if you're doing a straightforward select like above and not doing all kinds of funky joins and such.

Comment: No, every client that signs up on your service, will create their own contact lists, they wont be sharing with others.

Comment: Selecting by primary key is very fast, since primary keys are indexed. A million records is not much for a relational database, but if you are in doubt, create a million dummy records and try the select?

Comment: @AndrewNee are you very sure that a select like that wont cause much load?

Comment: you need to read up on database "indexes". they thought of this(speed problems with big tables) like 40 years ago.

Comment: A million isn't a big number in this case. You're better off having less fragmentation by keeping all contacts in one table. I would prefer the latter option.

Comment: The primary key has to be unique and since there will be multiple users belonging to the same contact list, you cant set their parent list as the primary key. @halfer

Comment: "Load" is a relative concept. A million records on a Raspberry Pi computer will probably max it out, but on a decent VPS it will be fine.

Comment: "you [can't] set their parent list as the primary key", so this is a foreign key, and you add a manual index it.

Comment: @halfer So what you are saying is that I have a table with the references, I should do selects with joins? Wouldn't that be more intense?

Comment: Well, use joins if you have to. Your example query doesn't have a join and is likely to be faster than another query that does have a join and returns the same number of records. But I reiterate my earlier point: if you ask us the speed of something, we are guessing since we don't know your hardware, nor the (join?) query you are proposing to run. The size of your dataset is also hazy at this point. So, create an example database, populate it with test data, and do some tests. That is a much better way to see what queries are best.

Comment: @halfer That is a very good reponse. Thank you so much for this explanation.

Comment: No problem. Consider using a local virtual machine for this, so you can set up a test system, and clone/destroy it as required. VirtualBox is the easiest solution, but Vagrant will give you more replicable results.

Answer (score 0):

> If you have 50,000 users, and each of them has 2 contact lists each of 10,000 emails, you have 1 million emails logged into 1 single table. Wouldn't it be too intensive to run a select query on that table like...

No

You need to consider the design and implementation of your MySql environment and queries but handling the scale you mention is not inherently a problem.

[Scale  Mysql](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/guide-to-scaling-web-databases-with-mysql-cluster/)

Answer (score 0):

A million records isn't a big number for a database - they're meant to handle such cases. You're better off having less fragmentation by keeping all contacts in one table - this way there will be no repetition.
 I would prefer the latter option.